# Nodejs Server Creation not running

Tags: node.js, unix, redis, nodes

iam very new to nodejs. I found difficult with this server creation program

```
var http =  require("http");
function onRequest(request, response) {
console.log("Request received.");
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("Hello World");
response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to mention the port number to listen.

Your code has to have aport number in the listen.

```
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8080);
```

The port number 8080 was already in use....So i used

another port number like 8083....It works...